# store scraped data in format like csv, json, mysql/sql, txt from selenium scrip using python

Tags: python, json, excel, selenium, web-scraping

I was scraping data from a website and I want to store this in a format like JSON, excel, sqlite or text format so that the data looks organised and sensible. Please help me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.amazon.in/Skybags-Brat-Black-Casual-Backpack/dp/B08Z1HHHTD/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=skybags&qid=1627786382&sr=8-2')

product_title = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "productTitle"))).text

print(product_title)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-hook='see-all-reviews-link-foot']"))).click()
    
while True:
    for item in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-hook='review']"))):
        reviewer = item.find_element_by_css_selector("span.a-profile-name").text
        review = ' '.join([i.text.strip() for i in item.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@data-hook='review-body']")])
        print(reviewer,review)

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@data-hook='pagination-bar']//a[contains(@href,'/product-reviews/') and contains(text(),'Next page')]"))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.staleness_of(item))
    except Exception as e:
        break

driver.quit()
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528801/how-do-i-write-data-to-csv-file-in-columns-and-rows-from-a-list-in-python

Comment: this is about CSV only, my preference is either JSON or mysql

Comment: You mentioned CSV in your question.

Comment: sorry for the communication gap but it want to know json or MySQL also with csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the values  `product_title`, `review` and `reviewer` in a dictionary and convert that to a Json format using `json` module.

You may store the data in this format and finally convert the list to JSON.

```
lst = [{"product_title": <title>, "reviews": [{"review": <review>, "reviewer": <reviewer>}, {"review": <review>, "reviewer": <reviewer>}....]
```

```
import json
json.dumps(lst)
```

**To write the data to a JSON file**

```
with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(lst , f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: how i will use this in for loop

Comment: We're here to help you and not to solve your entire problem without any effort from your end.

Comment: Well what data do you want to store as JSON ?

Comment: sorry my friend , i love those contributors who help each other and you are one of them Ram and as per your suggestion I applied this to my code and its working

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Comment: one last question the output is coming in one line only I want to add property like next line how can I do this

Comment: and the numbers are appearing in different way \u20b92,010.00 like this I think I should use utf-8

Comment: use of indent solved the next line property issue just want to know about the numerical error

Comment: Yes. Those are Unicode characters. Use ```ensure_ascii = False``` in ```json.dump()```.

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 1: character maps to <undefined> displaying this error after adding above statement

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: still displaying error 'ensure_ascii=False' is not working fine ERRR:    UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>